# Get correct data from input type="date" with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve the date from an `input type="date"`

My HTML code is `<input type="date" class="form-control" id="id_date" name="date" value="">`

I have a JS that read when the input type change and print on the console the timestamp

```
const date_value = document.getElementById('id_date')
date_value.addEventListener('change', function (e){
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.timeStamp)
    var date = new Date(e.timeStamp);

})
```

For some reason, I can get the actual date chosen from the input form as my function returns always the 1st Jan 1970. I know that `Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC but the form should return the milliseconds from that date to the date I have selected but it won't-

Below is a screen of my output. How do I manage this data?

[image: output date]

Comment: e.target.value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodday

As I can understand you just need to fetch the selected date from the input field and print it in the console.

then simply just do this...

```
const date_value = document.getElementById('id_date');
date_value.addEventListener('change', function (){
    console.log(date_value.value);
})
```

Whenever the user selects a date, the function will be called and it will console the update date value from the field.

I hope this will help you, still if you have any doubt please let me know comment below.

Comment: You don't need the *date_value* variable, `console.log(this.value)` is sufficient. ;-)